# C program: multi-word guessing game conversion error

Tags: c, output

I've just finished writing a pretty big chunk of a game which run perfectly but have a problem with converting guess words into asterisks with a space where there is a space.
For example if the words were "chicken nuggets" it should come out like 
"****** *******"
but instead it comes out "**************"
Since the code is far to long to post here I know this is the line I have gone wrong on but I can't figure out a work around yet.

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(words);i++){string[i]='*';}
```

any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please put your code in a code block, and post the entire code, so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Compute the length of the string ahead of the loop.
// Don't compute it in every run of the loop.
int len = strlen(words);
for ( i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   if (!isspace(words[i]) )
   {
      words[i] = '*';
   }
}
```

Comment: You should not recompute the length of the string upon each iteration. Your code is very inefficient.

Comment: @chqrlie, I am aware of that. I was making minimal changes to OP's code to get them going. Good observation, though.

Comment: I should have been more specific. The OP seems very much unaware of that.  Use every occasion to teach about classic mistakes.